# Is there an IRC channel?

Tags: discussion

Is there an IRC channel that posts recent questions like there was for Stackoverflow?

Comment: I'm sure someone will set one up .. just be sure to invite chanserv :)

Comment: There's going to be an IRC-like "third place" for all SE sites, as discussed on meta.stackoverflow.com. I am guessing that one part of the third place will be something posting recent questions.

Answer (score 2):

No, but there will be this.. soon..ish.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/

Keep an eye on http://blog.stackoverflow.com for a more public beta of this "third place" next week!